# Counting navigation property occurrence

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, razor

if I have the following two `models`:

```
public class Book
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    //other properties
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}


public class Category
{ 
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

And I'm sending `List<Book>` to the View:

```
public class ShopController : Controller
{
    private BookStoreMDFEntities db = new BookStoreMDFEntities();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var list = db.Books.Include("Category").ToList();
        return View(list);
    }
}
```

How can I view the Category names and occurrence number of each category in this `Book` list?
**Sample Output**:

- Science : 2
- Maths:4 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Anonymous type way

If you're using Entity Framework, you can do the following:

```
var list = db.Category.Select(c => 
new { 
    Name = c.CategoryName, 
    Count = c.Books.Count
}).ToList();
```

and then send it to your view and render with `@foreach` in Razor.

### List< Book > scenario

Provided that you really need to send `List<Book>` to view instead, you might group books inside view:

```
@{
    var list = Model.GroupBy(b => b.Category.CategoryName);
}
@foreach (var entry in list)
{
    <div>@entry.Key : @entry.Count()</div>
}
```

Comment: The purpose of my question was to accomplish that by sending the `Book` model not the category . 
basically i intended to do that because i'm sorting the books as they're being sent to the `View` how ever if i send the `Category` model i'll be down for so much work to sort the navigation property `Books` in it ,also i could've sent the `Category` model and viewed the count of each category as `Model.Books.Count` as Books is an `ICollection<Book>` in Category .
which as well won't give 100% success the `Books` will be sorted each within their `Category` **not an effective sorting**

Comment: I've edited my answer to meet your requirements. Please be more precise **next time ;)**.